# winforms draw border and move when FormBorderStyle set to None

Tags: c#, winforms, border, move

I display a winform as a dialog (with ShowDialog over a main window).
So, I set the FormBorderStyle to None because I wanted neither the control boxes nor the title bar.
Though, I would like a border drawn (for example a blue border like normal windows) and keep the ability to move the form.
I don't need the ability to resize it.
I tried to draw a border by overriding OnPaint but it is never called.
Here is my code :

```
  protected override void OnPaint (PaintEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnPaint (e);
    int borderWidth = 2;
    Color borderColor = Color.Blue;
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder (e.Graphics, e.ClipRectangle, borderColor,
      borderWidth, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid, borderColor, borderWidth,
      ButtonBorderStyle.Solid, borderColor, borderWidth, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
      borderColor, borderWidth, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid); 
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please use the formatting tools available to mark code, makes it much more easier to read questions this way...

Comment: Your code works fine when I paste it into a form.

Comment: I suppose the code is good, it is just not called !

Answer (score 3):

The `Paint` method is wrong here since it does not paint the so-called non-client area of the form, e.g. the border and the title bar.

To hide the title bar, you need to set the `ControlBox`property to `false` and clear the form's `Text` property. Set the border to `FixedDialog` to make the form unresizable.

To retain the ability to move the form without the title bar, you need to override `WndProc`.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    switch (m.Msg)
    {
      case 0x84: m.Result = new IntPtr(0x2);
          return;
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Basically this is the standard way of handling [WM_NCHITTEST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645618%28VS.85%29.aspx) message and cheating, saying - the mouse cursor is on the window's caption [return value 0x2], so you will be able to move your form even if you click in the client area and drag it.

Comment: The OnPaint method is fine, he set the FormBorderStyle to None.

Comment: Though, the code for the move is not working, case is missing and Result is IntPtr, it cannot be assigned 0x2. Besides, I would like to change the size and the color of the border.

Comment: So, can anybody help with these 2 problems left : moving the window and changing the size and color of the border ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the corrected version. An int can be assigned to IntPtr either with new IntPtr or by casting.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was to have a resizable form with a thin border.

I set FormBorderStyle to None

I use a docked panel who contains all my controls.

I use the panel padding to set my borders width.

And then :

```
Point ResizeLocation = Point.Empty;
        void panResize_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
                ResizeLocation = e.Location;
                ResizeLocation.Offset(-panResize.Width, -panResize.Height);
                if (!(ResizeLocation.X > -16 || ResizeLocation.Y > -16))
                    ResizeLocation = Point.Empty;
            }
            else
                ResizeLocation = Point.Empty;
        }
        void panResize_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && !ResizeLocation.IsEmpty) {
                if (panResize.Cursor == Cursors.SizeNWSE)
                    Size = new Size(e.Location.X - ResizeLocation.X, e.Location.Y - ResizeLocation.Y);
                else if (panResize.Cursor == Cursors.SizeWE)
                    Size = new Size(e.Location.X - ResizeLocation.X, Size.Height);
                else if (panResize.Cursor == Cursors.SizeNS)
                    Size = new Size(Size.Width, e.Location.Y - ResizeLocation.Y);
            }
            else if (e.X - panResize.Width > -16 && e.Y - panResize.Height > -16)
                panResize.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNWSE;
            else if (e.X - panResize.Width > -16)
                panResize.Cursor = Cursors.SizeWE;
            else if (e.Y - panResize.Height > -16)
                panResize.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNS;
            else {
                panResize.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            }

        }

        void panResize_MouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ResizeLocation = Point.Empty;
        }
```

Comment: I change your code a bit and works for me. Thanks for share!

Answer (score 0):

As no more information seems available, I will leave the border as suggested, set to FixedDialog with ControlBox property set to false and the form's Text cleared.
I would prefer another color for the border and the ability to move the window though.
Anyway thanks a lot for the answers.

Comment: To have a custom border you'll need to do your own non-client area calculations and painting. Let me say that it's a bit complicated when using the managed code. Maybe it's better to set the border to None after all and paint your "border" (this would be a fake one, something that only visually looks like one) using a function you listed in code or some other (DrawRect or whatever).