# Drawing a gripper in a borderless form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

So I've got a borderless form and I need it to be re-sizable (by clicking any of the 4 sides or the corners). To clarify, I want my form to be borderless like the default sticky notes in Windows 7.

[image]

I've got it to work (on bottom right corner only for now) by using the code provided by Julien Lebosquain on this post:

[Resize borderless window on bottom right corner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535826/resize-borderless-window-on-bottom-right-corner/1535943#1535943)

However, I would really like to display the drag gripper image on the bottom right corner. In his post, Julien mentioned this regarding the gripper:

> you can initialize a new
>   VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.Status.Gripper.Normal) and
>   use its `PaintBackground()` method.

I'm not sure how to go about doing this within my form. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: What you want, it to be drag by 4 corners and 4 sideways also or only from 4 corners ?

Comment: 4 corners and 4 sides. However, My immediate priority is to get the gripper image to show on the bottom right corner to show that my form is re-sizable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So after reading up on it a bit here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstyleelement.status.gripper.normal.aspx, I've got the solution.

First override the `OnPaint()` event for the form.

```
   protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
       base.OnPaint(e);
       DrawGripper(e);
   }
```

And the method that does the drawing.

```
   public void DrawGripper(PaintEventArgs e) {
       if (VisualStyleRenderer.IsElementDefined(
           VisualStyleElement.Status.Gripper.Normal)) {
           VisualStyleRenderer renderer = new VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.Status.Gripper.Normal);
           Rectangle rectangle1 = new Rectangle((Width) - 18, (Height) - 20, 20, 20);
           renderer.DrawBackground(e.Graphics, rectangle1);
       }
   }
```

Comment: +1, good one, to make it clear use `Invalidate();` in `DrawGripper();`

Answer (score 1):

See this post at **CodeProject** http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/borderlessform.aspx

Comment: thanks for helpful link. Any idea how I can get the grip icon to show on the bottom right corner?