# White line in inherited from QGraphicsView customized window

Tags: c++, qt

My window class is inherited from QGraphicsView. In constructor of my class I set

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::CustomizeWindowHint);
```

But after showing my window there is a strange white line on top that I can't remove. Where is a problem? Did I missed something?

UPD1: [screenshot](http://s018.radikal.ru/i509/1608/ae/506f941c5007.png)

UPD2: I also tried on Qt5.6.1 - the same result. Qt[5.4.2||5.6.1], Win10(x64)

UPD3: I setted red backround for my window. And [here is a new screen](http://prnt.sc/c99ohv) that shows better my situation.

UPD4: Well, seems it's a [Win10 Bug.](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-47543). My friends tried my app in older Windows and it works as I expect.

Comment: Maybe a screenshot would help?

Comment: Cant reproduce your problem, works fine with my qt 5.7 for linux 64bit. Mind providing more details?

Comment: I use Qt5.4.2 and can't use later version. OS - Win10(x64)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this combination of flags:

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint)
```

Comment: Yes, that helps, but I need resizable window. I have already tried that, but forgot to say this. But thank you!

Comment: You can implement such functionality by yourself. For help, you can look for this artical: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752408/qt-resize-borderless-widget