# Resize borderless window wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, transparency

How could I do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535826/resize-borderless-window-on-bottom-right-corner) with wpf instead of windows forms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>Here is a [sample](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/getwpfcodebywillhan/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1578) in WPF.</strike> And another [blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20120719040808/http://blog.kirupa.com/?p=256) with a different sample.

Comment: Both of these links are dead now

Answer (score 7):

You can do it by setting WindowChrome.

```
        /* Set Borderless Chrome to this Window */
        WindowChrome Resizable_BorderLess_Chrome = new WindowChrome();
        Resizable_BorderLess_Chrome.GlassFrameThickness = new Thickness(0);
        Resizable_BorderLess_Chrome.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(0);
        Resizable_BorderLess_Chrome.CaptionHeight = 5.0;            
        WindowChrome.SetWindowChrome(this, Resizable_BorderLess_Chrome);
```

Add the above code inside the window constructor to obtain border less resizable window.
Or you could use the window style setter to set the window chrome property:

```
<Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
        <Setter.Value>
            <WindowChrome CornerRadius="0" GlassFrameThickness="1" UseAeroCaptionButtons="False"/>
        </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

In addition to this you need to set ResizeMode to CanResize (or CanResizeWithGrip whatever that suits your purpose) and Window Style to None.

[Refer MSDN link for more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.windowchrome.aspx)

[If you are looking for Metro UI like window please check this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592326/making-wpf-applications-look-metro-styled-even-in-windows-7-window-chrome-t)

Comment: Great. It should be noted though that this is .NET 4.5 API.

Comment: You can use shell integration library to get the same functionality in .NET 4.0 . http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell . Though there is significant namespace changes.

Comment: Meantime I've found out that [WindowChrome](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.shell.windowchrome.aspx) is also part of Microsoft's [Ribbon UI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799534%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for .NET 4 that can be [downloaded here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11877), although only one DLL from the package is needed to get WindowChrome.